# Searching MongoDB nested tree object

Tags: mongodb

Suppose if I have a JSON object like below in MongoDB as one of the item in a collection.

```
data:{
name:"newData",
items:
      [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "1. dragon-breath",
        "items": []
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 21,
            "title": "2.1. tofu-animation",
            "items": [
              {
                "id": 211,
                "title": "2.1.1. spooky-giraffe",
                "items": []
              },
              {
                "id": 212,
                "items": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 22,
            "title": "2.2. barehand-atomsplitting",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "3. unicorn-zapper",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 30,
            "title": "3. unicorn-zapper.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "id": 300,
                "title": "3. unicorn-zapper.1.1",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "id": 3000,
                    "title": "3. unicorn-zapper.1.1.1",
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "id": 30000,
                        "title": "3. unicorn-zapper.1.1.1.1",
                        "items": [
                          {
                            "id": 300000,
                            "title": "3. unicorn-zapper.1.1.1.1.1",
                            "items": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "4. romantic-transclusion",
        "items": []
      }
    ]
```

It is a continuous tree structure and all items doesn't necessarily need to have the "title" property. How do I search for an item with a title for eg {"title":"3. unicorn-zapper.1.1.1"} in the whole structure and return only that item. any ideas.

Comment: This is not outsourcing portal, where you dump your job and other people do it for you. Show some effort and then ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to search arrays more than one deep as of MongoDB 2.6.5, except by searching by index using dot notation. Even then, there isn't a way to project just the matching array element of the matching document for arrays more than one deep. I think that you did not consider how you were going to query your documents before you structured them. If you have nested/tree-like structure in your data, read over the [data modeling docs on trees](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) for advice about how to model this situation better than using arbitrarily-nested arrays.

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley. I have no control over the data. But I have already solved it by doing a recursive for loop(C# driver) to find the item(s) although I thought there should be a better way as MongoDB is built for this purpose.